# Suggest a CAPTCHA image

Tags: discussion, top-7

According to [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-attributes), we need a CAPTCHA image for the site, don't we? Let's hear some suggestions.

Comment: Wouldn't using images from existing games be breach of Copyright? - In response to the suggestions posted already.

Comment: Then the current one does too. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

how about our **R**obotic **O**perating **B**uddy ([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqh80.jpg))

[image: R.O.B.]

Comment: i like it because it's so obscure...

Comment: I wish is could upvote more than once...

Answer (score 4):

[GlaDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLaDOS) from Portal

[image: GlaDOS]

(or similar)
[source: wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Glados.jpg)

Comment: You might want to explain that this is GLaDOS from Portal.

Comment: @ChrisF right, sorry. I only used an alt-text...

Comment: I don't think a captcha would fall under fair-use.

Comment: Don't think Valve is the kind of company that cares about that though.

Comment: @Noctrine Why should they *not* appreciate us advertising for [Portal 2](http://www.thinkwithportals.com) for *free*?

Answer (score 3):

Dog from Half-Life 2:

[image]

Image from [Gamasutra.com](http://gamasutra.com/)

Answer (score 1):

And to attempt to answer my question, I propose the **Star Control 2 Chmmr**:

[image: Chmmr idle animation]

Star Control 2 is now under the **GPL** license so I hope there won't be any copyright issues.

Answer (score 1):

What about Mother Brain:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about a Gearmo from Super Mario Galaxy:

[image]

Image from Enter-Play.com

Comment: man i hated that guy's second "clean up my garbage" star in SMG1. i think that was the toughest one for me...

Comment: And not a Whittle or Jibberjay? XD

Comment: @Raven - you can always suggest those yourself...